# overlapping windows in pdcurses/ncurses

Tags: c++, ncurses, overlapping, pdcurses

I need help with my first program, which is using an additional library: pdcurses (ncurses). I created the pop-up window and it works. The problem is when I try to delete this window. As you might guess, though I deleted it, the blank spaces are still there. At first I thought that it wasn't a big deal, I could just recreate the background (another window) again. Nothing could be further from the truth. When I'm recreating the windows using create_rightwin(col, row);, create_leftwin(col, row); again, it breaks this part of these windows, which haven't any contact with  the pop-up window. It looks like attron is on, and all titles in other windows are reserved. I've read in the internet that I should use wintouch(), but I don't have any idea how and when to do it. Did anyone have any similar problem?

Comment: Post a complete actual program that shows the problem.

Comment: Also, in general, if you want to have overlapping windows in curses, you should use the panel library.

Comment: @WilliamMcBrine: I've heard about panel library, but I thought that using it don't solve the problem but only "avoid" it. There is my program. Comments are in polish languages, sorry for that.
http://pastebin.com/CMqkGQFc

Answer (score 1):

As noted, the [`panel`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/panel.3x.html) library solves problems of painting and updating overlapping windows.  Both pdcurses and ncurses provide a `panel` library.

The ncurses programming how-to has a section on the panel library (which includes an example):

- [16. Panel Library](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/panels.html)

The how-to originally came with a zip-file with the sources, which seems to have been mislaid.  There is a copy of that linked in the ncurses FAQ in a section listing the how-to along with some other [reference material](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#for_reference).

The ncurses sources include several test-programs (not as simple as the how-to); a few of these demonstrate the use of `panel`.  Those test-programs are separately available as [*ncurses-examples*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-examples.html).

The `panel` library is also supported in a few bindings from other languages than C, as discussed in these pages:

- [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile-ncurses/manual/html_node/The-curses-panel-library.html)
- [Perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=913244)
- [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21172087/i-need-an-example-of-overlapping-curses-windows-using-panels-in-python)
- [Ruby](http://graysoftinc.com/terminal-tricks/curses-windows-pads-and-panels)